# Generating Icon Files

Tags: icons, favicon

I'm looking for an online solution for generating .ICO files.  I'd like the ICO files to have the ability to have transparency as well.

What software or web site do you use to create them?

[Update]

To clarify, I have an existing image in PNG format, 32 x 32 pixels.  I want to generate the icon from this existing file, not create a brand new one online.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the application [IcoFx](http://icofx.ro/) useful, you can import pretty much any image type to use for icon creation, including PNG's.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon Icon Sushi a little while back and love it. It hasn't been updated in about a year, but it still works great, even in Vista. Plus it is free.

http://www.towofu.net/soft/e-aicon.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), it's freeware and allows you to convert to ICO. It even allows you to select the transparent color.

I've used it a lot in my projects, since a WinForm needs an ICO file for it's icon, while I usually have PNG or BMP files.

Answer (score 1):

I like [MicroAngelo](http://www.microangelo.us/).

Answer (score 1):

I also use Gif Movie Gear to create `.ico` files.

This online [Favicon Generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) tool also seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite method is a photoshop plugin to "Save as .ICO".

http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html

Fast, works offline, you're already in Photoshop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[png2ico](http://winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/) is what I've always used, and perfect for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try, it has support for vista style Icons

Axialis IconWorkshop Lite for VS 2008

http://www.axialis.com/download/iwlite.html

Axialis Software, in association with Microsoft Corporation, presents Axialis IconWorkshop Lite for Visual Studio 2008:

```
* 100% Free for Visual Studio 2008 users;
* Make icons for Windows up to 256×256 PNG-compressed icons for Windows Vista™ and include them in your software projects;
* Use an advanced icon editor with various tools, filters and effects;
* Work efficiently using a Plug-in for Visual Studio 2008;
* Create icons from images or ready-to-use image objects;
* Use a fully integrated workspace with librarian, built-in file explorer with thumbnail preview, image viewer and more…
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine drawing icons online.  Nowadays icons are usually *drawn* as vectors, and I'm not aware of any online vector packages.

In case you decide to draw off-line instead, I use Xara (www.xara.com) to draw all my computer artwork, and I use Gif Movie Gear to create .ico files.   The former is a superb vector package, the latter is just something I have lying around.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple program called MyViewPad, which can convert (almost) any old image to a .ico file.  It's free and easy to use.  This may not be what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Otto, if you could clarify what it is that you need this for, and we are more likely to have good suggestions.  Provide a use-case, and someone will probably have some advice to fit it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that needs to be done often and automatically, or is this just a one time thing for your app?  If the latter is correct, MyViewPad will work.

Answer (score 0):

I use [InkScape](http://www.inkscape.org/) with is a free vector graphics program.

Answer (score 0):

I use [GIMP](http://www.thegimp.org/) for my icon design, but it's quite a bit of a pain having to join all the layers together then creating different layers for each icon size before exporting. Hmm maybe I could make my next project writing a plugin for the GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled up Greenfish Icon Editor Pro a while back and its been working great for the simple icons I have been needing to make.

[Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://greenfish.extra.hu)

The only downside is that it is windows only.

Answer (score 0):

With http://www.favicon.cc/ you can either draw your own, or upload a jpg, jpeg, gif, png, bmp, or ico. And it's a web app, so there's nothing to install. Works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

When creating icons for my apps using VS, I simply use Paint (32x32) to draw it and save as PNG, then I go to http://www.online-image-editor.com/, upload my PNG, click on the Wizards tab, click the Transparent button, then click on the points in the image I want to make transparent (usually, just the white sections.)  I then save the image, go to another web site at http://prodraw.net/online-tool/pic-to-icon.php, upload the saved image from the previous site, set my Preference options, convert, and download. Viola, a transparent icon!  Other than the actual drawing of the original image, it literally takes just a couple of minutes.